# How can I set the global default date format in Java?

Tags: java, date, jdbc

Is there a way to set the default DateFormat class used for parsing strings into dates?

My background: I get exceptions reading date values from JDBC because the date string is not in the expected format.

*(text added on 2011-07-22):*

Seems I need to precise my question description: I use a foreign, proprietary database together with a proprietary JDBC driver. There is no possibility to know or even change the column type on database side. When I try to read the ResultSet columns via ResultSet.getDate() or ResultSet.getObject() some exception is triggered inside the JDBC driver like "10 Jul 1999 is not a valid date". What I want to achieve is to avoid this internal exception by setting some appropriate global default date format. Maybe I would need to implement some custom Locale first and the install that Locale globally?

Comment: is this in an application server or a stand-alone application

Comment: How are you reading the date from JDBC? Which format do you get from there?

Comment: How are dates presented in your database? Why are you getting them as Strings and not as java.sql.Date or java.sql.Timestamp from JDBC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set your default Locale:

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
```

Alternatively, you can use one of the `DateFormat` static methods which accepts a Locale to just get the format for the Locale you're interested in. If your date format doesn't match one of the standard ones, you'll need to create your own `SimpleDateFormat` (based on a pattern) and make sure you always use that one instead of the default one.

Comment: @AlexR: my understanding of "the default DateFormat class" is the format(s) returned by the static methods of `DateFormat`, which depend only on the current Locale. @blerontin, if that's not what you mean, let me know and I can delete the answer.

Comment: I guess setting the default Locale _could_ work if there would be some Locale with the fitting date format (it should be "dd MMM yyyy"). Is it possible to derive a custom Locale and install that?

Comment: Actually by browsing all implemented locales with `DateFormat.getAvailableLocales()` I found an existing locale that fits my required default date format (en_MT). So this tip solved my issue!

Comment: @blerontin: OK, I'm glad it helped, although now that I understand your issue better, I agree with BalusC there should really be no need! Clearly there's a problem with the database itself, although obviously there's nothing you can do about that.

Answer (score 7):

There should be totally no need for this.

Dates should be stored in DB as a `DATE`, `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` field, depending on the DB used and the information you'd like to store (e.g. date only or date and time combined), not as a `VARCHAR` or something. Such a date-specific field stores the value under the covers basically as an integer/long with the epoch time as value.

Assuming that you're using a date+time field type such as `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`, then you should be saving it in the DB using [`PreparedStatement#setTimestamp()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp%28int,%20java.sql.Timestamp%29). Here's an example, assuming that the `date` variable is of a [`java.util.Date`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) type:

```
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
```

And you should be retrieving them from the DB using [`ResultSet#getTimestamp()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getTimestamp%28java.lang.String%29) which returns a [`Timestamp`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) which in turn is a subclass of `java.util.Date`, so you could just safely upcast it:

```
Date date = resultSet.getTimestamp("columnname");
```

As to parsing/formatting the `java.util.Date` object from/into a human readable `String` format, this should technically happen in the view side, not in the persistence layer. How exactly to do this in turn depends on the view/UI technology/framework used, such as Swing, JSP, JSF, Struts2, Spring-MVC, etcetera. As it's not clear from your question which one you're using, it's not possible to give a suitable answer. In general, they all use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) API under the covers. You could even use it in raw form.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know the exact column type on database layer and there is no possibility to change it. This is some foreign legacy database that I am interfacing with. I have updated the description regarding that, now.