# Convert timestamp long to normal date format

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

In my web app, date & time of a user's certain activity is stored(in database) as a timestamp `Long` which on being displayed back to user needs to be converted into normal date/time format.

*(Actually my database Cassandra stores the timestamp of when a column was written to it, as a long value( microseconds since 1970 ) which I will use to find out the time of that corresponding user activity)*

I am using JSF 2.0(+ primefaces) which I believe has converters that may be helpful for this conversion? Or otherwise how How can I, at best, achieve these conversions?

Comment: I know nothing about Cassandra, so here's just a shoot in the dark: I wonder if `PreparedStatement#setTimestamp()` and `ResultSet#getTimestamp()` doesn't work out for you? See also the answer on a similar question which I posted before today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778558/how-can-i-set-the-global-default-date-format-in-java With a fullworthy `java.util.Date` object you can just use JSF standard date/time converters such as `<f:convertDateTime>` in the view side the usual way to convert between it and a human readable string representation.

Comment: @BalusC: isn't Cassandra is one of those `BigTable` or `NoQuery` database that facebook or twitter use. I heard those are very different from regular DB. @Raj, since `PreparedStatement#setTimestamp() and ResultSet#getTimestamp()` might not work for you, I post higher layer solution for you.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Let me propose this solution for you. So in your managed bean, do this

```
public String convertTime(long time){
    Date date = new Date(time);
    Format format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MM dd HH:mm:ss");
    return format.format(date);
}
```

so in your JSF page, you can do this (assuming `foo` is the object that contain your `time`)

```
<h:dataTable value="#{myBean.convertTime(myBean.foo.time)}" />
```

If you have multiple pages that want to utilize this method, you can put this in an `abstract class` and have your managed bean extend this `abstract class`.

**EDIT: Return time with TimeZone**

unfortunately, I think `SimpleDateFormat` will always format the time in local time, so we can't use `SimpleDateFormat` anymore. So to display time in different TimeZone, we can do this

```
public String convertTimeWithTimeZome(long time){
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    cal.setTimeInMillis(time);
    return (cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) + " " + (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + " " 
            + cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + " " + cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":"
            + cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

}
```

A better solution is to utilize `JodaTime`. In my opinion, this API is much better than Calendar (lighter weight, faster and provide more functionality). Plus `Calendar.Month` of `January` is `0`, that force developer to add `1` to the result, and you have to format the time yourself. Using `JodaTime`, you can fix all of that. Correct me if I am wrong, but I think `JodaTime` is incorporated in `JDK7`

Comment: Thanks ! could you also let me know how can I convert(increment/decrement) it according to the user's local timezone.

Comment: There's [JSR-310](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/threeten/index.php?title=ThreeTen), a proposed standardised Joda-Time-alike library to appear in a future JDK, but it didn't make it into JDK 7.

Comment: @ThangPham JodaTime is not incorporated in JDK7.

Comment: It is added to JAVA SE 8

Comment: This doesn't provide leading 0 when second,minute or hour is single digit. I have modified it to make look like a digital clock. 
User formatting to achieve the same as below :
String curTime = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE), cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
        
or Check my answer in comments

Answer (score 3):

### java.time

```
    ZoneId usersTimeZone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Tashkent");
    Locale usersLocale = Locale.forLanguageTag("ga-IE");
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.MEDIUM)
            .withLocale(usersLocale);

    long microsSince1970 = 1_512_345_678_901_234L;
    long secondsSince1970 = TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.toSeconds(microsSince1970);
    long remainingMicros = microsSince1970 - TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMicros(secondsSince1970);
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = Instant.ofEpochSecond(secondsSince1970, 
                    TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.toNanos(remainingMicros))
            .atZone(usersTimeZone);
    String dateTimeInUsersFormat = dateTime.format(formatter);
    System.out.println(dateTimeInUsersFormat);
```

The above snippet prints:

> 4 Noll 2017 05:01:18

“Noll” is Gaelic for December, so this should make your user happy. Except there may be very few Gaelic speaking people living in Tashkent, so please specify the user’s correct time zone and locale yourself.

I am taking seriously that you got microseconds from your database. If second precision is fine, you can do without `remainingMicros` and just use the one-arg `Instant.ofEpochSecond()`, which will make the code a couple of lines shorter. Since `Instant` and `ZonedDateTime` do support nanosecond precision, I found it most correct to keep the full precision of your timestamp. If your timestamp was in milliseconds rather than microseconds (which they often are), you may just use `Instant.ofEpochMilli()`.

The answers using `Date`, `Calendar` and/or `SimpleDateFormat` were fine when this question was asked 7 years ago. Today those classes are all long outdated, and we have so much better in `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API.

For most uses I recommend you use the built-in localized formats as I do in the code. You may experiment with passing `SHORT`, `LONG` or `FULL` for format style. Yo may even specify format style for the date and for the time of day separately using an overloaded `ofLocalizedDateTime` method. If a specific format is required (this was asked in [a duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50599303/how-to-convert-the-datetime-long-into-hhmmss-dd-mm-yyyy-format)), you can have that:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss, dd/MM/uuuu");
```

Using this formatter instead we get

> 05:01:18, 04/12/2017

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if JSF provides a built-in functionality, but you could use `java.sql.Date`'s constructor to convert to a date object: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#Date(long)

Then you should be able to use higher level features provided by Java SE, Java EE to display and format the extracted date. You could instantiate a `java.util.Calendar` and explicitly set the time: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setTime(java.util.Date)

EDIT: The JSF components should not take care of the conversion. Your data access layer (persistence layer) should take care of this. In other words, your JSF components should not handle the `long` typed attributes but only a `Date` or `Calendar` typed attributes.

Answer (score 0):

To show leading zeros infront of hours, minutes and seconds use below modified code. The trick here is we are converting (or more accurately formatting) integer into string so that it shows leading zero whenever applicable :

```
public String convertTimeWithTimeZome(long time) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        cal.setTimeInMillis(time);
        String curTime = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE), cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
        return curTime;
    }
```

Result would be like : 00:01:30

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and worked for me.

```
Date = (long)(DateTime.Now.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0))).TotalSeconds
```

Answer (score -1):

long timestampMillis = timestampMicros / 1000;

// Convert milliseconds to LocalDateTime
LocalDateTime dateTime =

LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(timestampMillis), ZoneOffset.UTC);

// Format LocalDateTime to string using custom formatter

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");

// Format LocalDateTime to string

System.out.println(dateTime.format(formatter));

Comment: This answer was [already given at May 30, 2018 at 10:03 by user 'Anonymous'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50601849). On contrary to old fashioned discussion forums, there's on Stack Overflow no need to repeat an already given answer upon agreement. Just up vote it if it helped you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).