# Create actual date in string format from microseconds with precision of microseconds

Tags: java, java-8, java.util.date

I want to create a java.util.Date object from microseconds. But i don't want to lose its precision microseconds to millisecond. Currently i am converting microseconds to Date object in the following way.
If i pass microseconds to the Date constructor then it gives a wrong date like `56521-12-01`.

```
long microSeconds = value.getTimestampValue();// This function returns a microseconds.
DateFormat FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS);
long millis = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(microSeconds, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS);
String startDate = FORMAT.format(new Date(millis));
```

I don't want to convert microseconds to milliseconds. Is there is a method of API or java-8 utility where i can direct convert the microseconds to Date object?

The problem with this method is It remove the last three digits of microseconds to make it milliseconds then create a date object from milliseconds  and parser just multiply its milliseconds part with `1000` to convert it into microseconds. In this way i lost a actul microsends.

Comment: Your first mistake was attempting to use java.util.Date in Java 8.

Comment: I searched for the solution but i can't find the exact solution. So, I use a Date object. Could you tell me the solution

Comment: LocalDateTime could be a valid alternative. Could it be suitable for your purpose?

Comment: This question is related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/1712215/274340

Comment: @AM13 yes i can use LocalDateTime. Can you give a solution in answer ?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `Instant`, `DateTimeFormatter` and other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create Java DateTime Instant from microseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57411881/create-java-datetime-instant-from-microseconds) And/or this? [Convert timestamp long to normal date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782185/convert-timestamp-long-to-normal-date-format)

Comment: Show sample data.

Answer (score 7):

## tl;dr

```
Instant                                                  // Represent a moment as a count since the epoch reference of 1970-01-01T00:00Z.
.ofEpochSecond(                                          // Instantiate a `Instant` as a count of whole seconds plus fractional second.
    TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.toSeconds( microseconds ) ,    // Count of whole seconds since the epoch reference.
    TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.toNanos( microseconds )        // Calculate fractional second as a count of nanoseconds.
    - 
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos( 
        TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.toSeconds( microseconds )
    ) 
)                                                        // Returns an `Instant`.
.toString()                                              // Generate text in standard ISO 8601 format.
.replace( "T" , " " )                                    // Replace a `T` with a SPACE for desired output format.
.replace( "Z" , "" )                                     // Remove the `Z` from the end, that indicates the date and time is in the context of UTC.
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Furthermore, as others indicated, the **legacy classes cannot accommodate microseconds**, only milliseconds. Well, actually, the legacy class `java.sql.Timestamp` attempts to represent nanoseconds, but does so by way of a terrible hack that includes a fractional second in milliseconds *and* a fractional second of nanoseconds (a real mess).

## java.time

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

### Sample data

For a demo, let's create the sample number of microseconds since the first moment of 1970 in UTC.

```
// Convert to microseconds. Use as input value to further code below.
Instant instantPrime = Instant.now().truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.MICROS ); // Drop any nanoseconds, to keep only microseconds.
long wholeSecondsPrime = instantPrime.getEpochSecond();
long nanoAdjustmentPrime = instantPrime.getNano();
long microseconds = 
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMicros( wholeSecondsPrime ) + 
    TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMicros( nanoAdjustmentPrime )
;
```

### Processing

Let's chop that count of microseconds into two parts, a number of whole seconds since 1970-01-01T00:00Z, and a fractional second as a number of microseconds.

```
// Convert from microseconds.
long wholeSeconds = TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.toSeconds( microseconds );
long nanoAdjustment = TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.toNanos( microseconds ) - TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos( wholeSeconds );
```

Put them back together again.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond( wholeSeconds , nanoAdjustment );
boolean match = instant.equals( instantPrime );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "instantPrime = " + instantPrime );
System.out.println( "wholeSecondsPrime = " + wholeSecondsPrime );
System.out.println( "nanoAdjustmentPrime = " + nanoAdjustmentPrime );

System.out.println( "microseconds = " + microseconds );

System.out.println( "wholeSeconds = " + wholeSeconds );
System.out.println( "nanoAdjustment = " + nanoAdjustment );
System.out.println( "instant = " + instant );

System.out.println( "match = " + match );
```

> instantPrime = 2020-01-07T23:32:26.385565Z
>
> wholeSecondsPrime = 1578439946
>
> nanoAdjustmentPrime = 385565000
>
> microseconds = 1578439946385565
>
> wholeSeconds = 1578439946
>
> nanoAdjustment = 385565000
>
> instant = 2020-01-07T23:32:26.385565Z
>
> match = true

### Strings

Generate text representing the value of your `Instant` using standard ISO 8601 format.

```
String output = instant.toString() ;
```

> 2020-01-07T23:32:26.385565Z

Your desired format is close to that. Replace the `T` with a SPACE. And remove the `Z`, though be careful about that. Presenting date-time as text without indicating the time zone or offset-from-UTC can create ambiguity and confusing for the reader. I would recommend including the `Z`.

```
String output = instant.toString().replace( "T" , " " ).replace( "Z" , "" ) ;
```

> 2020-01-07 23:32:26.385565

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Thank you so much @Basil for insight details :)

Comment: I execute the same above code on my machine but it will print time differently.
`instantPrime = 2020-01-08T11:29:19.065Z
wholeSecondsPrime = 1578482959
nanoAdjustmentPrime = 65000000
microseconds = 1578482959065000
wholeSeconds = 1578482959
nanoAdjustment = 65000000
instant = 2020-01-08T11:29:19.065Z
match = true`

It only shows the time in milliseconds.

Comment: @KhalidShah Are you running Java 8? That version used an implementation of [`Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Clock.html) that captured the current moment in milliseconds. Some implementations of Java 9 and later uses a new `Clock` that captures the current moment in microseconds. The *java.time* classes can represent nanoseconds, but conventional computer hardware clocks are not that accurate.

Comment: Yes i am using java 8

Answer (score 5):

You won't be able to do this using `java.util.Date`. [From the API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html):

> The class Date represents a specific instant in time, with millisecond precision.

Comment: My use case is only convert microseconds to` string representation of actual time` with microseconds precision. I can use  other classes instead of Date.

Comment: @KhalidShah Then you should **edit** the question and say that.

Answer (score 4):

```
int seconds = (int) (microSeconds / 1_000_000);
int nanoSeconds = ((int) (microSeconds % 1_000_000)) * 1_000;
LocalDateTime t = LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(seconds, nanoSeconds, ZoneOffset.UTC);

String s = t.toString(); // with a T
s = t.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME); // with a T
s = t.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"));
```

Date has a milliseconds resolution. And the new time classes are far better, though need a bit more effort.

Comment: Missing `()` at `int seconds = (int) (microSeconds / 1_000_000);`

Comment: Wrong class. The `LocalDateTime` class cannot represent a moment as it lacks the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC. Change to `OffsetDateTime`.

Comment: Thanks @JoopEggen its really hepful :)

Answer (score 1):

If your string contains milliseconds, then firstly we need to choose the appropriate pattern for it.

```
String date = "2021-11-15T07:45:28.655";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
LocalDate dt = LocalDate.parse(date, formattter);
```

It resolves your problem.

If it includes time zone as well, then you need to change the pattern again.

```
String date = "2021-11-15T07:45:28.655-08:00";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz");
LocalDate dd = LocalDate.parse(date, formatter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative using LocalDateTime:

```
LocalDateTime date =
LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(millis), ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

However If you just want a sort of "well formatted timestamp" you can use just:

```
LocalDateTime.now()
```

Comment: The Questions is about microseconds, not milliseconds.